# Executing stored procedure Query Failed with no error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i m trying to make an insert to a table in SQL Server 2008 but i get an Query Failed with no error at all.

This is my Stored Procedure:

```
USE [ACREDITA]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VICOM_INS_IMPACTO]
@IMPC_NOMBRE varchar(100),
@IMPC_OTRO varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(200) = 'TRANSACTION'
BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName
BEGIN TRY
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    IF(@IMPC_NOMBRE = 'otro')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO
                VICOM_IMPACTO_MAESTRA(VICOM_IMPACTO_NOM,VICOM_IMPACTO_OTRA)
            VALUES
                (@IMPC_NOMBRE,@IMPC_OTRO)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @OTRO varchar(100) = NULL

            INSERT INTO
                VICOM_IMPACTO_MAESTRA(VICOM_IMPACTO_NOM,VICOM_IMPACTO_OTRA)
            VALUES
                (@IMPC_NOMBRE,@OTRO)
        END

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName
    --------------------------------------------------------        
END TRY        
BEGIN CATCH
    --------------------------------------------------------
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TranName
    --------------------------------------------------------
    EXEC ('ACREDITA_GuardarError')
END CATCH

SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END
```

The input i'm trying to send with post is the following:

```
<form action="Backend/grabar_ficha.php" id="ficha_vicom" method="post"       name="ficha_vicom" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
         <legend>Impacto en la formaci&oacute;n de los estudiantes:</legend>
         <select class="form-control input" name="impacto" onchange="impactoOtro(this);" required >
             <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
             <option value="Formación académica">Formaci&oacute;n acad&eacute;mica</option>
             <option value="Actualización de contenidos">Actualizaci&oacute;n de contenidos</option>
             <option value="Desarrollo práctico y experiencial">Desarrollo pr&aacute;ctico y experiencial</option>
             <option value="otro">Otro</option>
          </select><br>
                            <input type="text" name="impactoO" value="sin info" class="form-control impactoOtro" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counterImp',100);" maxlength="100" placeholder="especifique" style="display: none;" required />
                            <input value="Caracteres restantes 100" disabled class="counter" id="counterImp" size="25" style="display: none;">
          </fieldset><br>
</form>
```

I m getting the values of the "impacto" and "impactoO" fields this way...

```
//Variables impacto actividad
    $impactoO = $_POST['impactoO'];
    $impacto = $_POST['impacto'];
```

And then calling a php function that calls the SP

```
$id_impacto   = $db->VICOM_INS_IMPACTO($impacto, $impactoO);
```

The PHP function is the following:

```
function VICOM_INS_IMPACTO($name,$otro){

    if($name != "otro"){
        $otro = "null";
    }

    $this->query = "execute VICOM_INS_IMPACTO 
        @IMPC_NOMBRE  = '".utf8_encode($name)."',
        @IMPC_OTRO  = '".utf8_encode($otro)."'";

    $res_ = $this->DB_Insert();     
    return $res_;
}
```

All other functions that work similar way works fine but for some reason this one doesnt.

I can't use mssql_last_message and i m not receiving any specific error message.
I have the

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

What you guys think could be happening?

Thank you so much for your help.

**Edit**:

These are the errors that i m getting:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in /web/sites/umayor/acreditacion/AMBTE_PRD_V2/ficha_vicom/Backend/Database.php on line 71





Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/sites/umayor/acreditacion/AMBTE_PRD_V2/ficha_vicom/Backend/Database.php on line 77
```

I m also printing the query that i m sending and this is whaty i get:

```
SQL statement failed with error QUERY = execute VICOM_INS_IMPACTO   @IMPC_NOMBRE = 'FormaciÃƒÂ³n acadÃƒÂ©mica', @IMPC_OTRO = 'null'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()` be inside the catch block?

Comment: yes, i did that only to test if the SP returns something. I tried with it and without it.

Comment: what happens when you try to run the Stored Procedure independently with the same parameter values in SQL Query Analyzer?

Comment: I dont have Query Analyzer but if i try to execute sp inside sql server it DOES execute succesfully.

Comment: I m getting the following errors:   Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in /web/sites/umayor/acreditacion/AMBTE_PRD_V2/ficha_vicom/Backend/Database.php on line 71

Comment: Do you have access to SQL Profiler?  If you do you can watch what your php code is passing to SQL Server.

Comment: @RickGittins it doesn't show the execution of the specific SP. i dont know why.

Comment: Can you see other stored procedures running in SQL Profiler?

Comment: @RickGittins yes all other SP in the process are running. I have another SP almost with the exaclty same process and it does run well.